# CSS - how to overflow from div to full width of screen

Tags: css

I have a containing DIV, that I use as part of my responsive grid. It expands to the maximum width I allow which is 1280px, then margins appear for large devices. Here's my CSS + a bit of Less.

```
.container
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width:1280px;
    padding:0 30px;
    width:100%;

    &:extend(.clearfix all);
}
```

However on some occasions I'd like to overflow sideways - lets say I have an background image or colour that needs to be full width. I'm not great at CSS - but is it possible to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The most obvious solution is just to close the container...have your full width div then open a new container. The title 'container' is just a class...not an absolute requirement that it hold **everything all at the same time**.

In this instance you apply the background color to the full width div and you don't *need* to apply a color to the internal, restricted div.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.fullwidth {
  background: orange;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #663399;
}
.mydiv {
  /* background: orange; */
  min-height: 50px;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
</div>
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mydiv">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum illum veniam in delectus corrupti autem magnam. Tenetur ducimus provident nisi aut esse aliquid accusamus quas.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mydiv">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum illum veniam in delectus corrupti autem magnam. Tenetur ducimus provident nisi aut esse aliquid accusamus quas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

However, for some they like a *single* all encompassing container so if all you are after is a background you could use a pseudo-element like so:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #663399;
}
.mydiv {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.mydiv:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  background: orange;
  z-index: -1;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum illum veniam in delectus corrupti autem magnam. Tenetur ducimus provident nisi aut esse aliquid accusamus quas.</p>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Support for `vw` is IE9+ - See [**http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

There are cases where actual content is required in the 100% wide div and the container cannot be opened/closed at will (perhaps to retrofit a slider).

In those cases, ***where the height of the new div is known*** the same technique can be used to position it as to be 100% viewport wide:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #663399;
}
.mydiv {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.myslider {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  background: orange;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <div class="myslider">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum illum veniam in delectus corrupti autem magnam. Tenetur ducimus provident nisi aut esse aliquid accusamus quas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0kohr1qv/1/)

Note: there are instances where `100vw` can cause overflow and a horizontal scrollbar might appear. `overflow-x:hidden` on the `<body>` can attend to that..it should not be an issue because everything else is still inside the container.

Comment: @Paulie_D I noticed an issue with jQuery animation on your second solution with pseudo-element. Adding these jQuery code `$('.mydiv').hide();
$('.mydiv').slideDown();` will give you a funky animation. Do you have any idea to get around with this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you have the basis for a question of your own.

Answer (score 24):

I found this **super useful trick** by using `vw` on `margins` ([Source](http://blog.cloudfour.com/breaking-out-with-viewport-units-and-calc/))

**Example :**

```
.inner-but-full {
   margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
   margin-right: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}
```

**Demo :**

```css
html,body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent scrollbar */
}

.inner-but-full {
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  margin-right: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(28, 144, 243, 0.5);
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-but-full"></div>
</div>
```

**Can I use :**

http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">p{text-align:center;margin-left:25%;height:300px;width:50%;border:1px solid red;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;padding:0;
} body{margin:0;text-align:center;height:100%;width:100%;max-width:100%;max-height:100%;}</style>
<p style="color:yellow;background-color: red;">yep</p><p style="color:red;background-color: yellow;">yep</p><p style="color:white;background-color: blue;">yep</p>
```