# Filling a specific height range to a color in css

Tags: html, css

If I have a body tag and I want to change the background color to grey from the top of the page down say 300px, how would I do this if I have content on the page over the body?

I can set the entire background color of the body tag to grey, is it possible to just define a range?

```
body {
    background-color: #16749F; // from 0px to 300px 
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create two div's with different colours and set heights?

Comment: because the way the pages are set up right now. I have the body and inside the body I have a div with a bootstrap container. The container has padding and margin values so everything lays in it with white space around it. Which is what I want for everything except the top part of the page where there is a nav menu. I want the nav menu background color to span the entire page, but I want to keep everything else inside the container

Comment: Outside of the container create another div element as <div class="container-fluid"></div> and maybe add another class for example <div class="container-fluid grey-bg"></div> then set the grey-bg to the color and height?

Comment: if I do this it pushes the other content down.

Comment: I used position is absolute. thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like you might need this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to avoid modifying the HTML, you can do something like:

```css
body:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    background: #16749F;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <p>Your current site content.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a background image with a solid grey colour and repeat it along the x-axis. It would have a 1px width amd 300px height.

```
body {background:white url(../img/grey_bg_1x300.gif) repeat-x 0 0;}
```