# full width line within bootstrap container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap `container` (`div class="container"`) and there are two `rows` (`div class="row"`).

But between those rows I need one **full width horizontal line**. Full width - I mean that it should be **full width - outside** `container`. This line is just for design issues, it would have background color and that is it. I do not know how to create it.

Comment: Probably similar to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide your content into 2:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    stuff here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="line"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    stuff here
    </div>
</div>
```