# How to extend a div to the left without exceed .col-md-3 margins?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to extend a `div` to the left, but I want this `div` to match the `margin-right` of a `.col-md-3` like so:

[image: Extend DIV to the left, without exceed bootstrap col]

I have tried with relative values for the red div, but that solution didn't make it responsive, absolute values even worst. Also tried with a CSS gradient but as the relative values, it didn't work responsively.

If is a big screen, the red div should be extended to the left but the right margin should match with the right margin of the `.col-*` (or just the `.col-md-3` for now) and the content within the red div should fit the `.col-md-3`.

How can I achieve a responsive solution for this?

Thanks for the help in advice!

Comment: please can you create a [MCVE]

Comment: What is the purpose of this red div?

Comment: Like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564131/bootstrap-full-width-with-2-different-backgrounds-and-2-columns

Comment: Thank you @Paulie_D, that's exactly what I wanted to achieve!