# How to break out of foundation row and stick to right edge of viewport

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, codepen

I have an example of zurb foundation grid on codepen. I'm trying to think of a way to extend a div to the right edge of the viewport but keep the left edge inline with the grid as the viewport is resized.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="my-custom-block">
      MY CUSTOM BLOCK ==> Please extend to right edge of viewport
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**
I don't mind if the solution is outside the grid and doesn't use Foundation. I just want the my component to match the start of the grid but stay flush to the right of the viewport when resized.

[image: zurb example]

[example on codepen](https://codepen.io/coder2013/pen/NwNPLZ)

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564131/bootstrap-full-width-with-2-different-backgrounds-and-2-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the row class has a defined width/max-width with `margin:auto` on it. If you don't mind changing row to a percentage max-width you could do something like this:

```
.row {
 max-width: 62.5%;
}

.special-row {
 overflow:hidden;
 width: 100%;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 0;   
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 //this is halfway between the 62.5% above and 100%
 max-width: 81.25%;
}
```

Comment: Would you fork the example and demonstrate it works?

Comment: The problem is your arbitrary % value may not match the left margin of the grid

Comment: Sorry, I missed the custom block in the example. I updated the codepen fork. Basically I closed the parent div.row before the custom block and changed .row to a percentage max width instead of em.This would obviously require some media queries to look nice on some widths.

Comment: Thanks for trying but as I suspected this approach doesn't keep the left side level with the start of a row

Comment: Please refresh the pen. I hadn't saved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158190/discussion-between-git-e-up-and-neil).