# image out of container

Tags: html, css

It's possible to do image 100% width (out of container right side)?
Im using bootstrap4, i need something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT9oJ.jpg
My code is:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    Tekst
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
    <img alt="Web Studio" class="img-fluid"         src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solodev/vertically-centering/master/images/vc-img-1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    Tekst
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
    Opis newsa
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: sometihing like this? [Similar scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360757/image-outside-container-only-one-side/51360987#51360987)

Comment: @Matt Yes, but i didn't received a good answer. Using % width is wrong idea.

Comment: You have 24 columns in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think you should change the `<div class="container">` to `<div class="container-fluid">` and add padding to the right. add this class to your css.

```
.container-fluid {
   padding-left:20%; /*any width you want %,px,em*/
}
```

Place this on another row

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Tekst
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
       Opis newsa
    </div>
 </div>
```

Then on the `Opis newsa` you use `col-lg-6` there