# How to code two colored full-width header?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm codding new website. How to code this layout? I need a full-width header, but one side is gradient (4 cols) and another is white (8 cols).
Layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN2Ec.png

I could use a flexbox, but I can't put a bootstrap grid inside it.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have tried to research it and have tried to code.

Comment: And you have to **demonstrate** that research.

Comment: However - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564131/bootstrap-full-width-with-2-different-backgrounds-and-2-columns

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you. I am going to try to use a "before" and "after" elements

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="header"></div>
```

just use linear-gradient like this

```
.header {
  background: linear-gradient(
   to right,
   #ff9e2c 0%,
   #ff9e2c 50%,
   #b6701e 50%,
   #b6701e 100%
  );
  height: 100%; //what height or width u want
  width: 100%;
}


</style>
```

[image]

use can use it like

```
  background: linear-gradient(
   to right,
   #ff9e2c 0%,
   #b6701e 50%,
   #b6701e 100%
  );
```

too but effect change

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have create `col-4` and `col-8` in your `header` and apply **background individually**. If you apply gradient to your header without `column` it'll create problem for you in **different resolutions**. I create a very basic example for you, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.white-bg {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.gradient-bg {
 background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 gradient-bg">Gradient Background</div>
  <div class="col-8 white-bg">White Background</div>
 </div>
</header>
```