# bootstrap one column within container and other column extend to screen edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve something like this.

[image: 6 column and 6 column fluid]

I have tried container fluid and manually setting margin-left on the left column, but this is not 100%.
I also tried different variations from this article, but this did not work either.
https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Markup would be like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">left column</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">right column should extend to right screen edge</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap version ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564131/bootstrap-full-width-with-2-different-backgrounds-and-2-columns

Comment: Any latest version would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 4 + version, try below in your second div tag

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-md-right pr-md-0">right column should extend to right screen edge</div>
```

Comment: This won't because there is also margin for container on both sides.

Comment: Try 
<div class="container pr-md-0">

Comment: This way it left margin would be doubled because container has fixed width and mx auto.

Answer (score -1):

try this way (Bootstrap 4)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-md-right pr-md-0">
      Images
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/9Lrhwboc/2/

Comment: Your fiddle does not seem to show the issue being resolved.