# How to pull an element out of its container to the left OR right browser edge when image ISN'T in a centred container

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to create a layout as shown in the image here, where:

- I have a three column layout
- A div element is as wide as two columns
- In the div that is two columns wide is an image which i need to pull out to the left to the browser border, and the right side to the image to remain as wide as the two columns to it stays "stuck" to the right

[image]

I've used this code, and applied it to the image within the column, but do be honest I don't understand what it does:

```
margin-left: calc( -100vw/2 + 100%/2);
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="col-1"><img src="blabla" /></div>
<div class="col-2">Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
max-width: 1400px;
display: block;
margin: auto;
}

.col-1 {
float: left;
width:66.666%;
}

.col-2 {
float: left;
width: 33.333%;
}

.col-1 img {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin-left: calc( -100vw/2 + 100%/2);
}
```

The result is it pulls out to the left browser edge but the right side of the image doesn't remain in place.

I don't understand what i need to do to achieve this layout, and maybe it's not even possible.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlJVZ.jpg

Comment: Should be a link at the bottom?

Comment: Ah ok, added basic CSS & HTML, thank you

Comment: This is a lot more complex that you might think. What happens when the viewport is less that the max-width of your container?...What is supposed to happen to the image/content?

Comment: ..and is this **actual** content or just a styling thing?...If it's a background image we have options. Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564131/bootstrap-full-width-with-2-different-backgrounds-and-2-columns

Comment: No, its an actual image. This layout is for certain widths only, on mobile etc the layout stacks, but this layout needs to be responsive when the browser is wide enough to accomodate the content

Comment: I think it *could* be managed with CSS-Grid but I'd have to think on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple math:

**You have to calculate 2 parameters**
1. the shift of the `<img>` -- (1/2 of `viewport` width - 1/2 of `.wrapper` width),
2. `width` of the `<img>` -- (100% of `.col-1` + shift from the above)

**Where**
1. width of the `viewport` -- `100vw`
2. width of `.col-1` -- `100%` of `.col-1`
3. width of `.wrapper` -- `150%` of `.col-1`

*The `<img>` is a child of `.col-1` so the `%` dimensions are relative to `.col-1` width.*

**Let's calc**
1. `shift` = `(100vw/2 - 150%/2)` = `(50vw - 75%)`
2. `width` = `(100% + 50vw - 75%)` = `(25% + 50vw)`

**Please note**
`margin-left` should be negative to shift left so
`margin-left` = `(75% - 50vw)`

You may run the snippet in fullscreen and resize the window: it's responsive.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80vw; /* for example, may be any */
  max-width: 1400px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper div {
  border: solid 1px
}

.col-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 66.666%;
  background: #693
}

.col-1-2 {
  width: 50%
}

.col-2 {
  width: 33.333%;
  background: #e43;
}

.col-1 img {
  display: block;
  width: calc(25% + 50vw);
  margin-left: calc(75% - 50vw);
  opacity: .75; /* for example verbosity */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
    <div class="col-1-2">Content</div>
    <div class="col-1-2">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you! Can you explain the math?

Comment: @SteveMcC, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Grid can come close to what you are looking for...but I'm hesitant on the responiveness of the image.

FWIW.

```css
.super-con {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto repeat(3, minmax(auto, 500px)) auto;
}

.super-con div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.image {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
  display: block;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="super-con">
  <div class="image"><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/150/150" alt=""></div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good but it doesn't seem to pull the image out to the left to remain attached to browser window…