# Twitter bootstrap, columns cover entire width of screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This meta tag is used to stretch bootstrap columns so something like `<div class="col-sm-12">` would cover the entire width of the screen. Is it possible to apply this to only part of a page, the meta tag that is.

Comment: This meta tag is used to control how your site is viewed on mobile devices, and it affects the entire page. From what you've said, I'm guessing you mean a mobile version is having issues. If so, you may wish to try deleting `initial-scale=1`.

Comment: no it's for the webpage, I want the columns to be stretched, but only for a specific part of the page, a specific row. The rest should be normal.

Comment: `col-sm-12` is always the full width, independent of the viewport. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen Also, your premise is incorrect. That meta tag has nothing to do with 'stretching columns' at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite, check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to better understand what that meta tag does.

If you want part of your page to span the entire width of the display, simply wrap that section of the page inside

```
<div class="container-fluid">YOUR_CODE_HERE</div>
```

instead of the regular

```
<div class="container">YOUR_CODE_HERE</div>
```

Ensure that the `container-fluid` tag is not wrapped inside a parent tag that has a set width.