# LESS Horizontal Positioning Absolute with Relative Vertical Positioning

Tags: html, css, less

I have a container div that I need to set the horizontal positioning to absolute to make it full screen width (just like a fluid container). Then I need to set the vertical positioning to relative so that it stays where the content is..
Is this possible in LESS? There's a lot going on here in the project with gutters, so it's nearly impossible to work around this unless I can do it in this one class. Basically, I'm tied to this answer.

Note: I've seen this question answered for CSS, but not for LESS.

Basically I need to do this, but have the vertical position has to stay relative. (example in css):

```
.content-section-c-container {
   position:absolute;
   background-color: #3D8DC7;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not `position: relative; width: 100%;` ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do (or why). could you explain AND provide a minimal demo of the issue.

Comment: I wish, it's just making 100% of the width of the container it's currently in. :(

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/sRNrFm3.jpg I'm trying to make the blue the full width, but the project is so huge it will take me forever to modify the 'gutters' etc.. , The content above the blue isn't fixed content..so I have to somehow do the full width while ignoring the parent container.. Any ideas?

left/right 0 with absolute ignore the parent container.

Comment: Then the linked SO question I gave is the answer.

Comment: You're 100% correct sir! Thank you very much! Just saved my whole evening!

Comment: Would you like to post that as your answer to get credit?