# CSS: Make inner div 100% body width without using position:absolute - is it possible?

Tags: html, css

Lets assume for some reason I can not change the HTML, neither use JavasScript. Lets assume the position of `#content_actual` depends on the height of `#element`. `#element` has a flexible height.

Is there a solution for this problem?

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="element">ABCDE</div>
  <div id="content_actual">FGHIJ</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
  width:960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#element {
// width: 100% of body width
// position: everything but position absolute or fixed
}
```

Comment: Why the restriction on the position property?

Comment: Because if the element is position:absolute or position:fixed then the element is completely removed from the document flow and therefore #content_actual will be below of it or can only be position using a fixed height (which i do not have)

Comment: What is the purpose of this 100% wide div?

Comment: Showing a full width image which can be clicked away. Height of the image may change dynamically.

Comment: So the image is already in the HTML?

Comment: As you mentioned, the document flow is important. But included in the document flow is the relationships the elements have. Without using position absolute or fixed, or using JS I don't really see a viable solution.

Comment: Perhaps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen

Comment: @Paulie_D - Is that not a dupe?

Comment: Not *exactly*, I don't think although I'd have to do a thorough review. I may add my answer below to the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of relative positioning, viewport units and `calc`.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GZBOjY)

**NOTE:** this breaks as soon as the viewport is less than the container width. Media queries would be required at that point.

```css
#content {
  width: 480px; /* numbers changed for this Snippet */
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
  padding: 50px;
}
#element {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  right: calc(50vw - 240px); /* second value 50% of container width */
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="element">ABCDE</div>
  <div id="content_actual">FGHIJ</div>
</div>
```

It should also be noted that the container cannot have `overflow:hidden` for this technique to work.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Paulie_D's (apparently we were sharing brainwaves) but this uses percentage to counter the container width. No idea how well supported this would be:

https://jsfiddle.net/7w2cwqfq/4/

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="element">ABCDE</div>
  <div id="content_actual">FGHIJ</div>
</div>

#content {
width:200px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: yellow;
}

#element {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  width: 100vw;
  background: red
}
```

Comment: Even a bit nicer however think he answered the main problem first therefore +1