# fill the width of the remaining screen space (across container)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 Alpha 3 ([Flexbox enabled version](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/)).

<kbd>[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/e9upjwgq/1/)</kbd>

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
[class^="col"] {
  background: gold;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cask.scotch.io/bootstrap-4.0-flex.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      AA
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      BB
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      CC
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      DD
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

Is there a way (especially using Flexbox) to let `BB` fills the width of the remaining screen space (across `container`) like below? Thanks

[image]

Comment: You could set container so it has no right margin, then add right margin to every last in line div

Comment: Is this purely a cosmetic background effect or will BB have content all the way to the viewport edge?

Comment: @Paulie_D it does have content, but only background is to the viewport edge

Comment: So the content will be limited to the container?

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BB element is an in-flow flex item and is confined to its container (`.row`).

To make it overflow its parent and take the remaining width of the viewport, you can try this:

```css
.container > .row:first-child > .col-xs-10 {   /* 1 */
  position: absolute;                          /* 2 */
  width: 100%;                                 /* 3 */
  margin-left: 16.7%                           /* 4 */
}

.container > .row:first-child {
  position: relative;                          /* 5 */
}

body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

[class^="col"] {
  background: gold;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cask.scotch.io/bootstrap-4.0-flex.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">AA</div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">BB</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">CC</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">DD</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/e9upjwgq/2/)

Notes:

1. Target the BB element.
2. Remove BB from the [document flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#normal-flow)
3. Arbitrary full width
4. Position BB to start immediately at the right of AA (which has a width of `flex: 0 0 16.66667%`)
5. Make container the bounding box ([*nearest positioned ancestor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)) for absolutely positioned children.

Of course, a (potential) problem with this method is item #3.

Because BB is absolutely positioned relative to its parent, we don't know the exact length to the viewport edge. Giving too much width can result in a horizontal scroll bar, as in my example.

One workaround is to apply `overflow-x: hidden` to the `body` element, which will remove the scrollbar, simply clipping BB at the viewport edge.

Or we can remove `position: relative` from the parent, therefore making BB relative to the viewport. This method can precisely size BB to the viewport edge, but at the expense of item #4: `margin-left` will no longer be precise.

But let's give it a try:

***EDIT: Aside from the `margin-left` deficiency, there's another flaw with this method. Instead of removing the example, I'm keeping it for learning purposes. See if you can find the problem before reaching the end :-)***

```css
.container > .row:first-child > .col-xs-10 {   
  position: absolute;                          
  width: 75%;                                  /* 6 */
  margin-left: 25%;                            /* 6 */
  left: 0;                                     /* 6 */
}

.container > .row:first-child > .col-xs-2 {    /* 7 */
    flex-grow: 1;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

[class^="col"] {
  background: gold;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cask.scotch.io/bootstrap-4.0-flex.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">AA</div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">BB</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">CC</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">DD</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/e9upjwgq/3/)

Notes:

6. BB is sized, aligned and positioned relative to the *initial containing block* (i.e., the viewport).
7. AA, which is sized in the original code with `flex: 0 0 16.666667%`, is given `flex-grow: 1` to fill any gaps between itself and BB.

Now BB ends precisely at the viewport edge. However, we've had to make AA "flex" a bit to prevent any gaps due to BB `margin-left` imprecision.

***EDIT: The problem with the method above is this: Because BB is absolutely-positioned it is removed from the document flow. This means that AA doesn't even know it exists. Hence, `flex-grow` on AA will expand it all the way to the edge of the container, not to the start of BB.***.

---

Other alternatives include:

1. Making the container full width, then managing the length and margins of flex items. (This would involve major alterations to the Bootstrap framework, which is why I didn't pursue it.)
2. JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that the background extending beyond the container is a **purely visual requirement** and it will not contain actual **content** we can use the techniques laid out in this [**Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen).

We absolutely position a pseudo-element that is 100vw wide behind the element in question and apply `overflow-x:hidden` to the `body` so we don't get horizontal scrollbars.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
[class^="col"] {
  background: gold;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.expando {
  position:relative;
  }

.expando::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100vw;
  background:inherit;
  z-index:-1;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cask.scotch.io/bootstrap-4.0-flex.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      AA
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 expando">
      BB
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      CC
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      DD
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```