# Overflow from div to full width of screen with alternating background color

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, alternating

I am using the modified snippet below [from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen) to create a max-width layout, but I'd like to change `.flex-parent:after {yellow}` to an alternating background color using pseudo selectors as shown by my attempt in SASS below.

Can I do this when `background:yellow` is already being targeted by a pseudo selector? Is it possible to target a pseudo selector within a pseudo selector, or am I going down the rabbit hole? I'd prefer to keep things semantic and not try adding extra divs.

HTML

```
<section class="container">
    <article class="flex-parent">
        <p>This is text in flex-parent (odd)</p>
    </article>

    <article class="flex-parent">
        <p>This is text in flex-parent (even)</p>
    </article>

    <article class="flex-parent">
        <p>This is text in flex-parent (odd)</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

SASS

```
.container{
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.flex-parent{
    border:1px solid blue;
    position:relative;

&:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    width:100vw;
    z-index:-1;
    background:yellow;

        &>:nth-of-type(odd){
        background-color:orange ;
        }

        &>:nth-of-type(even){
        background-color:red;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

> The CSS ::after pseudo-element matches a virtual last child of the
>   selected element. It is typically used to add cosmetic content to an
>   element by using the content CSS property. This element is inline by
>   default.

As it is a virtual child you can't select any further, but combining selectors is allowed, so what you can do is `:nth-of-type(odd)::after`.

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/ucqrbyk8/) to show what I mean, but you could do like this:

CSS:

```
.container{
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.flex-parent{
    border:1px solid blue;
    position:relative;

  &:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    width:100vw;
    z-index:-1;
    background:yellow;
  }

  &:nth-of-type(odd)::after{
    background-color:orange ;
  }

  &:nth-of-type(even)::after{
    background-color:red;
  } 
}
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer, for the only reason that it's easiest to read!

Comment: Interesting development: I needed to add `z-index:1` to `.flex-parent` in my own project to actually be able to see the text. Not sure why, but an easy solve!

Answer (score 0):

And also, if you want to make it more semantic, try like this:

```
  &:nth- {
    &of-type {
      &(odd)::after { background:orange; }
      &(even)::after { background:red; }
    }
    &child { // some other
      &(4)::after { background: pink; }
      &(5)::after { background: green; }
    }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/1oy01zt7/2/

Comment: Thanks for this @TheDefinitionist! That is some lean code right there :)

Comment: So to confirm, you would not use `>` to select a direct child of a pseudo element (like how I had written it), but `::` to combine them?

Comment: The `>` is up to you I don't know what your future plan is, you can use it if you want to point on direct childs but if you have many other childs in 2 or more levels deeper then I wouldn' use it at all, I would just give them a class to create a pointer and `::` only for pseudos like this or `::before`.