# Complex full width grid

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How can I have this header 'full width'. So that the image is on the left side of the screen. But that the content inside (President Jean ...) is in the grid?

[image]

I was thinking about creating a new container.

```
.container--full { max-width: 1400px; width: 100%; }
```

My .container grid has a max-width of 1170px. So my new container is wider than .container.

And then set a background-image, position left and background color grey.
Inside that .container--full, create .container

```
<div class="container--full">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</div>
```

Test with container-fluid.

[image]

```
 <div class="container-fluid" style="background-image: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/commission-header.png');">

    <div class="container">

            <div class="col-sm-3">

                    <div class="info">
                        President
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9">

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime obcaecati consequatur illum dolor quasi labore molestiae voluptatum consectetur laborum vel, modi nulla totam blanditiis quam sapiente, suscipit laudantium. Necessitatibus, eos.

            </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

CSS

```
.commission-business {
.container-fluid {
    background-color: $grey--lighter;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.info {
    background: red;
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen

Comment: add custom class to col-sm-3 and assign this style="background-image: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/commission-header.png');" to new class  and do background-size:cover or 100% so it will fit col-sm-3

Comment: using container-fluid is recommended instead of creating another one

Comment: Thanks ! Got it to work like you said :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use bootstraps 'container-fluid' class. [(learn more)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-container)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row>
        ... 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I know the container-fluid class. But how text block in the first column can't be aligned correctly this way. See new screenshot in question above.