# Edit width of the burger menu content but keep background full width

Tags: html, css, header, navigation, hamburger-menu

I'm very new to coding and am trying to create a website as practice, but I've hit a brick wall.

I want my navigation to have a full width background, but the content to be constrained to 1180px

I've tried using

```
width: 1180px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

the issue that I'm having is that doing this contained the clicked burger menu background.

html:

```
<header class="header">
  <a href="/" class="logo">LOGO</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

css:

```
.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.header li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #B3B3B3;
}

.header li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/zwirled/pen/PoPjxym

Any help is much be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen?lq=1

Comment: Thanks for this, although I'm not sure it helps my situation... 

I need the header to all stay as one tag for the burger menu to work (or so i think)... 
I've tried setting out in separate div tags but it breaks the menu so it doesn't perform as desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is position:fixed. Use a div element as a position aid.  The elements will take the div element as the containing block element. It being its direct descendant. Take the input element out of the div element to control the drop down. Add the margin: 0 auto for both the li and the position aid.

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <div class="positionaid"> 
    <a href="/" class="logo">LOGO</a>
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn">
      <span class="navicon"></span>
    </label>
   </div>
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
}
.header li, .positionaid {
   width:1080px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! I have updated my CodePen with this and it is almost right, however I also want the logo and burger menu icon items to be 1080px too.

https://codepen.io/zwirled/pen/PoPjxym

Here's an image of what I mean – sorry I should've done this from the beginning! 

https://imgur.com/rnicwoP

Comment: Thank you! But now my drop down menu is contained in the div, so the black background is no longer full browser width. I've updated the codepen so you can see the issue. Is there any way to make the black background full width?

Thanks for all your help!

https://codepen.io/zwirled/pen/PoPjxym

Comment: That's it!! Thank you so much for your help, I've been stuck on this for days!

Comment: You're welcome. Could you select my answer as accepted? Thank you.