# If it's in a main div with margin, make a div with a width of 100vw

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div with a width of 100vw to cover all viewing areas, however, it comes in a div with a margin, so I'm having trouble.

I've also included an image link below to help you understand.
[image: To further comprehend, consider the following image.]

[image: picture for the entire page]

```css
* {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

body {
    background: black;
    margin: 2rem 6rem;
    color: white;
}

/* About Section  */

.about {
    display: block;
    background-color: #2e3038;
    margin-left: -6rem;
    margin-right: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="about">
    <div id="col1">
      <h3>A co-founder at one of the world's largest communities.
      </h3>
      <p>

        The combined experience I have working at the top Fortune 500 companies has allowed me to develop a skill set that helps me in not just development but in every aspect of any business. <br> I'm proud to announce that I am now working at one
        of the world's largest communities teaching young minds about how to sell themselves as a developer and open them to a whole new world of opportunities.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
      <p>As a developer, you have everything available to you and all that's holding you back is yourself. <br> A quote I live by perfectly illustrates what I mean. <br> "How big would you dream, if you knew you wouldn't fail?" You've already gone through
        the hardest parts of being a developer, it's time to elevate your skills and become a leader in something you're passionate about. <br> I'm happy to chat over coffee some time about how I can help your company.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, I attempted to use margin-right, however, it would not work.

***I can't use inspect element since the design I'm attempting to replicate is in png format.***

Comment: I don't see margin but rather padding inside each section

Comment: Why are you applying margin to the `body`? That's usually the first thing that is removed

Comment: I've included a second image of the complete page so you can see why I included a margin in the body.

Comment: Well that's not really the way it's usually done. Add elements with the margins you want and leave the body alone. If you want a wider div change the margins

Comment: Alternatively, use a proper container for your central items and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen?lq=1

Comment: So you're saying that instead of adding margin to the body, I should apply margin to each div individually? am I correct?

Comment: or use a container with those margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close - you've just specified the wrong direction for `margin-right`:

```css
* {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

body {
    background: black;
    margin: 2rem 6rem;
    color: white;
}

.about {
    background-color: #2e3038;
    margin-left: -6rem;
    margin-right: -6rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="about">
    <div id="col1">
      <h3>A co-founder at one of the world's largest communities.
      </h3>
      <p>

        The combined experience I have working at the top Fortune 500 companies has allowed me to develop a skill set that helps me in not just development but in every aspect of any business. <br> I'm proud to announce that I am now working at one
        of the world's largest communities teaching young minds about how to sell themselves as a developer and open them to a whole new world of opportunities.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
      <p>As a developer, you have everything available to you and all that's holding you back is yourself. <br> A quote I live by perfectly illustrates what I mean. <br> "How big would you dream, if you knew you wouldn't fail?" You've already gone through
        the hardest parts of being a developer, it's time to elevate your skills and become a leader in something you're passionate about. <br> I'm happy to chat over coffee some time about how I can help your company.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Full Width Containers in Limited Width Parents | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read and respond to my query.