# How can I align an element to the edge of the page with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a design image like this:

[image: demo]

But I see this output:

[image: psd]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="container">
  <div class="card border-0">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 position-relative">
          <div class="position-absolute">
            <h2 class="font-bold heading h3 pt-3 pb-4 ps-5">
              <img src="./images/surprise.png" alt="">
              <span>درباره من</span>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <p class="small text-secondary">اطلاعات بیشتر در مورد من و فعالیت من</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
          <p>لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است. چاپگرها و متون بلکه روزنامه و مجله در ستون و سطرآنچنان که لازم است و برای شرایط فعلی تکنولوژی مورد نیاز و کاربردهای متنوع با هدف بهبود ابزارهای کاربردی
            می باشد. کتابهای زیادی در شصت و سه درصد گذشته، حال و آینده شناخت فراوان جامعه و متخصصان را می طلبد تا با نرم افزارها شناخت بیشتری را برای طراحان رایانه ای علی الخصوص طراحان خلاقی و فرهنگ پیشرو در زبان فارسی ایجاد کرد. در این صورت می توان امید
            داشت که تمام و دشواری موجود در ارائه راهکارها و شرایط سخت تایپ به پایان رسد وزمان مورد نیاز شامل حروفچینی دستاوردهای اصلی و جوابگوی سوالات پیوسته اهل دنیای موجود طراحی اساسا مورد استفاده قرار گیرد.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-main">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="دانلود">
            <span>دانلود رزومه</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The general overview

[image: gen]

Whatever I thought, How this is done, I don't know.

I am creating a simple Express web server that serves a landing page made with Bootstrap, but I can't get any Flexbox examples to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen

Comment: Please improve the snippet demo above so we can see your problem. We can't debug images. I assume you have some custom CSS that should be included.